# How many ways Webjobs can be triggered using C#?

Tags: c#, triggers, azure-webjobs

How many ways we can trigger Azure WebJobs?
Apart from:

- ServiceBus
- Queue
- Blob
- Table
- Timer

I am looking to use other triggers like websites down or cpu high usage to trigger webjobs. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There aren't built in listeners for the "management/monitoring" things like "website down" or CPU high, but you can piece together solutions.  Beware that the monitoring should be in a separate site (a site can't monitor if itself is down; a site shouldn't respond to high CPU activity by calling itself to do more work)

1. You can always write your own listening logic that spews a queue message to a QueueTrigger (or use HttpTrigger with Azure Functions)
2. You can get a lot of mileage out of polling & timers. For example, website down - you can have a webjob / Function running on a timer that pings your site and when it's down and then use techniques from #1 to trigger your job.